# How do you make multiple node.js command line processes talk to each other?

Tags: node.js, command-line, tcp, protocols

I am messing around with https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever, and am wondering in general if and how you send messages from one command line process to another.

On the web, you use HTTP to send requests back and forth.  But I've never had to do that type of thing with the command line before.  I know it probably has to do with ports and sockets,  but not so sure where to start…

Here's the basic setup:

You have a `mainProcess.js` and `childProcess.js`, and they are invoked independently from the command line.  Somehow, `mainProcess.js` must run a callback whenever `childProcess.js` sends it a message.

#### `./parent.js`:

```
var forever       = require("forever");
var mainProcess   = forever.start(["node", "mainProcess.js"], {max: 1, silent: true});
mainProcess.on("stdout", function(data) {
  console.log(data.toString().trim());
});
mainProcess.on("stderr", function(data) {
  console.log(data.toString().trim());
});
forever.startServer(mainProcess);
```

#### `./child.js`:

```
var forever       = require("forever");
var childProcess  = forever.start(["node", "childProcess.js"], {max: 1, silent: true});
childProcess.on("stdout", function(data) {
  // *send to parent process*
});
forever.startServer(childProcess);
```

#### `./childProcess.js`

```
console.log("A Message from a child process!")
```

One way to do it is to parse log files, but that seems like it'd get messy quick.  It seems like there's some protocol out there that will allow me to send direct messages from one process to another the same way you would with HTTP to a url.  How would you accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performing IPC in node.js can be accomplished in a number of ways. Built in, there is the `child_process.fork()` API: http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_processes.html#child_process.fork

In `forever`, there is an option, `.fork` which will tell forever to use the `child_process.fork()` API instead of `child_process.spawn()`:

```
var child = forever.start('script-using-fork-api.js', {
  max: 1,
  fork: true,
  silent: true
});
```

If you're looking for IPC mechanisms which go over the network checkout:

- http://hook.io
- http://github.com/nodejitsu/nssocket

Comment: forever has an example how to use send function: https://github.com/foreverjs/forever-monitor/blob/master/test/monitor/send-test.js